# SSH keys cached remotely?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, public-key-encryption

I wanted to install a new public key on a remote server. I created a keypair using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` on my Macbook, then added its public key to `authorized_keys` on the remote server. It is the only public key in that file left:

```
user@remote:~/.ssh$ cat authorized_keys
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCwNctIMgFSrvxrB/fX0eN2ew/nSHZWvY7gT3/wuZ3IpnumYtOA62Telc8M9tLu3bLsuh3O+/duhKTkW58jyEp2W8cC8hy+bWdZRvaV1jdBKtOyKb+KMFELWdxFFHd6PdMz+D9ElmDQlDqe2/Kw7SCjDiLnnuJbjoB+DycbPnlEMsecZAK73anlwfzs5iV6pzdqJw1u8+n4w6cpqgZJ6nyAIWhxxN3Ii0/H3Fbe5XiYezJJi4jtAmtLPd6JxoX17pNqtEl8dlI7rp4exq+HfVDVzKjRRA5fdyUmuWYrscBPrI/5Djvr+vJS3OizzZNdtXeuXbqT+89exjaswR2XEU/p
```

Locally, while I kept the old key, this is my new public key:

```
local:.ssh user$ cat id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCwNctIMgFSrvxrB/fX0eN2ew/nSHZWvY7gT3/wuZ3IpnumYtOA62Telc8M9tLu3bLsuh3O+/duhKTkW58jyEp2W8cC8hy+bWdZRvaV1jdBKtOyKb+KMFELWdxFFHd6PdMz+D9ElmDQlDqe2/Kw7SCjDiLnnuJbjoB+DycbPnlEMsecZAK73anlwfzs5iV6pzdqJw1u8+n4w6cpqgZJ6nyAIWhxxN3Ii0/H3Fbe5XiYezJJi4jtAmtLPd6JxoX17pNqtEl8dlI7rp4exq+HfVDVzKjRRA5fdyUmuWYrscBPrI/5Djvr+vJS3OizzZNdtXeuXbqT+89exjaswR2XEU/p
```

As you can see, this is the key added to `authorized_keys` on the remote server.
For the sake of it, here are the contents of my old public key, just to show they're entirely different:

```
local:.ssh user$ cat id_rsa_alt.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDJMTXjgk8KMUQpiOnx9R5gTDQhFUQbUPZCvrCbQXIIRP4I7MfhqDEWUqnsobOxeYXXtyV0s116iFwvc/4DaWCWQEcuvIcRiRekQRgqELJJfbSdXR70OyBQWn1SpVKbD93Ww2KE+KomrYl0Ocl92GGw39tr2Eyl0qNM/5MBiZk4Nm8cEM/NhROesj8Uj2dNDh9AheC9eGSFdCkS7l+F2+dpZc2aIGgbkQtortIE41hu3yZl/EnQlXIQU2OiOxdm9jROm6ndh5OQn8/e5JH8CyExjRnSCH+/XlqfSVujaXjPaM5rBNQlzIxdjjrFkg4MxE4g/QFF9g60e37ed43QSAcH
```

I'm able to connect using the new key, of course, **however my old key still works:**

```
local:~ user$ ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa_alt user@remote
Linux lxhalle 2.6.32-52-server #114-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 11 19:06:34 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Welcome to the Ubuntu Server!
 * Documentation:  http://www.ubuntu.com/server/doc
Last login: Thu Nov  7 10:51:23 2013 from IP
```

What's going on here? What else do I need to do to *unauthorize* a key, except removing it from `authorized_keys`?

Comment: have you enabled master connections ? Just close every SSH session, kill any instance of a SSH client, and try again: If it fails, it was just a master connection that was still around.

Comment: I did not enable anything like that. My config file only contains shortcuts to type "ssh school" etc.

Comment: Is there an `authorized_keys2` file on the server ?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Ran into something similar. Turns out I had a private key id_rsa in the OS X login keychain that was getting used even after I deleted the file in ~/.ssh on disk. It wasn't until I deleted the entry in keychain access and restarted that key was no longer being picked up and used by the ssh command. Also worth mentioning that the "-v" switch to the ssh command is very helpful for debugging issues like this.